# Is it possible for template-class to inherit from multiple parents based on parameter pack?

Tags: c++

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
class C: public Wrapper<C1>, public Wrapper<C2>, public Wrapper<C3> ..... {}
```

...but pass any number of Cx as variadic template argument to class C:

```
template<typename... Cx>
class C: // ???????????????
```

Is it possible? Is there any workaroud for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

template <typename ...P>
struct C : P... {};

int main() {
    C<A,B> c;
}
```

or with a wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {};

template <typename ...P>
struct C : Wrapper<P>... {};
```

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example) you can find an example where the same is applied in the context of `std::visit`.

Comment: If you want to keep C as a class you can do `template<typename ...P> class C : public Wrapper<P>...{};`

Comment: @Wingreen C is a class.

Comment: Well since structs and classes are basically the same, okay. I just wanted to point out that the public keyword works.

Comment: @Wiingreen yes, sorry I actually understood what you wanted to say. It is just that it is an annoyingly persistent misunderstanding that a `struct` would not be a class.